# Extract row of data, and paste transposed with four blank cells in between each value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a script that extracts a row of data from one tab ("Weekly Selections"), based on criteria from a cell (Picks!J5) on another tab ("Picks"), and returns the list of data transposed in a column.

With the below script, the data is returned row-by-row in the below format. [image]

Is it possible to add 4 blank cells in between each value like in the below picture?[image]

I have included an example sheet for reference, along with my code below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LGPVbqoVYECAO9kZgWA5uL6EN4uUJt3F_IfjwhDfLlQ/edit#gid=474820972

```
sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
shForm = sh.getSheetByName("Picks");
shDb = sh.getSheetByName("Weekly Selections");
rng = shForm.getRange("B11:B46");
rng_val = rng.getValues()

   
function search(){

var rowNum = shForm.getRange("J6").getValue();

  if(rowNum === 0){
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("User not found!")
    
  }  else  {

    //get user team
    var data = shDb.getRange(rowNum,2,1,8).getValues()

    //display data to form
    //Defining a blank array that can hold the result
    trans = [];
    //transpose the data stored in range variable
    for(var column = 0; column < data[0].length; column++){
        trans[column] = [];
    for(var row = 0; row < data.length; row++){
        trans[column][row] = data[row][column];

      }
    }
    
    //printing values stores into trans variable on spreadsheet range
    shForm.getRange(11,9,8,1).setValues(trans);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your provided Spreadsheet, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please confirm the sheet names again.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Weekly Selections");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Picks");
  const [[v1], [v2]] = sheet2.getRange("J5:J6").getValues();
  const searchedRow = sheet1.getRange("A6:I" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues().find(([a]) => a == v1);
  if (!searchedRow) return;
  const emptyArray = Array(v2 - 2).fill([null]);
  const dstValues = searchedRow.slice(1).flatMap(c => [[c], ...emptyArray]);
  sheet2.getRange(11, 9, dstValues.length).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

- In this case, when "James" is selected at "J5" of "Picks" sheet, the value is set to `6` by the formula. And, when this script is run, the value of row 6 is retrieved from "Weekly Selections" sheet. And, the values of `Apples Oranges Bananas Apricots    Peaches Strawberries    Blueberries Blackberries` are put into the cells "I11:I". In this case, the empty rows between each word are 4.
- If you want to adjust the number of empty rows between each word, please modify `2` of `const emptyArray = Array(v2 - 2).fill([null]);`.

#### References:

- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike - Thank you for the response! We are very close here. The script you provided works for "James", but when switched to "Mike" the number of empty rows increases by 1 between each word.  Is there a way to keep it consistent at 4?  Thank you again - Greg

Comment: @Hocky295 Thank you for replying. About `The script you provided works for "James", but when switched to "Mike" the number of empty rows increases by 1 between each word. Is there a way to keep it consistent at 4?`, in this case, this depends on the formula of `=iferror(match(J5,'Weekly Selections'!A:A,0),0)` in your provided Spreadsheet. If you want to use the constant value, how about modifying your current formula to `=IF(COUNTIF('Weekly Selections'!A:A,J5)>0,6,0)`? By this, when the value of "J5" is existing, `6` is returned. In this case, my proposed script works for your expected result.

Comment: @Hocky295 In the case of the above modification in my comment, it is not required to modify my proposed script. If you want to achieve that without modifying the formula, please modify my script as follows. From `const emptyArray = Array(v2 - 2).fill([null]);` to `const emptyArray = Array(4).fill([null]);` If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, changing my original formula to =IF(COUNTIF('Weekly Selections'!A:A,J5)>0,6,0) corrected my issue. Appreciate your help!